# jQuery Datepicker Set Default Date to "current month, current day, (current year-18)"

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have a jQuery datepicker. I want to set the default date to "current month, current day, (current year-18)" but I have issue when I set the defaultDate property. The default year displayed is 1920 which is supposedly 1995. Can anyone help?

My code:

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" class="datepicker minimumSize" name="BirthDate" id="BirthDate"  readonly="readonly"/>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var d = new Date();
var year = d.getFullYear() - 18;
$('#BirthDate').datepicker({ changeYear: true, changeMonth: true, yearRange: '1920:' + year + '', defaultDate: d.getMonth()+d.getDay()+year});
```

**JSFiddle**
http://jsfiddle.net/jobzky/zg8Le/

Comment: Is someone making an 18+ site?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
var d = new Date();
var year = d.getFullYear() - 18;
d.setFullYear(year);
$('#BirthDate').datepicker({ changeYear: true, changeMonth: true, yearRange: '1920:' + year + '', defaultDate: d});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/zg8Le/5/)

Comment: I tried your demo. The default year in the dropdown is correct but I'm wondering that current day in the calendar is not selected. But if I remove the d.setFullYear(year); current day is now selected but default year is back to 1920

Comment: it is because of the condition, you are saying the year range is between 1920 and 1995 but default date is 2013, don't you see a mismatch there

Comment: I think removing d.setFullYear(year); will give still 1995 as the highest date since prior to this method we subtracted 18 years. The purpose of testing if we remove the d.setFullYear(year); is to check that current day is selected if included current day will not be selected

Comment: ah never mind buddy I think current day highlighting is just a css issue. Thanks your answer is the best

Answer (score 1):

In your fiddle you have `defaultYear` which  is not a valid option. Here you have `defaultDate` and by the way you're adding the day month and year together (also not likely what you mean) it seems you want to make it the date.

I suspect you want this instead:

```
$('#BirthDate').datepicker({ 
   changeYear: true, 
   changeMonth: true, 
   yearRange: '1920:' + year, 
   defaultDate: new Date(year,d.getMonth(),d.getDay())
});
```

Comment: The default date is correct but the selected day is not correct. It's not pointing to the current day

Answer (score 0):

try this .This will solve your problem

```
var d = new Date();
var year = d.getFullYear() - 18 ;

$('#BirthDate').datepicker({ 
    changeYear: true,
    changeMonth: true,
    yearRange: '1920:' + year, 
   defaultDate: new Date(year, d.getMonth(), d.getDate())
   });
```

Comment: sorry what do you mean? Isn't it yearRange is used when you want to be specific of what year from and year to will be displayed in the dropdown of year?