# Materialize Date picker year range in descending order

Tags: jquery, materialize

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
        selectMonths: true,
        yearRange: 100,
        format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
        autoClose: true,
        showClearBtn: true,
        close: 'Ok'
    });
```

when we click on year drop down list we should get current year first and then last year like
2019 this should be as selected
2018..
1919

Can someone help please?

Comment: Try to refer this and stackoverflow question : [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15491367/jquery-datepicker-set-default-date-to-current-month-current-day-current-year)

Comment: actually i need solution for materialize datepicker

Comment: Did you ever come right here?